# Derivative of a vector difference with Hadamard power

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian, hadamard-product

**What is the derivative of the following?:**

$ \frac{\partial( \hat{\mathbf{y}} - \mathbf{y})^{\circ2}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}}$

here $\mathbf{y}$ is a constant column vector of $n\times 1$ dimension.
$\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ is another column vector, with the same dimension.

**This is what I've been trying so far:**

from rules of Hadamard derivatives:

$= 2(\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{y}) \odot \frac{\partial( \hat{\mathbf{y}} - \mathbf{y})}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}}$

$= 2(\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{y}) \odot (\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}} - \frac{\partial {\mathbf{y}}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}})$

$= 2(\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{y}) \odot (\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}} - 0)$

$= 2(\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\mathbf{y}) \odot (\mathbf{I})$ (a vector's derivative of itself is the identity matrix)

Now, I am not sure how to do the Hadamard product between the vector($n \times 1$), and the matrix $(n \times n)$ works - and was wondering whether I did something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable
$$\eqalign{
x &= {\hat y}-y &\implies dx &= d{\hat y} \cr
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \cr
w &= x\odot x \cr
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of that last variable.
$$\eqalign{
dw &= 2x\odot dx = 2X\,dx = 2X\,d{\hat y} \cr
\frac{\partial w}{\partial{\hat y}}
 &= 2X = 2\,{\rm Diag}\big({\hat y}-y\big) \cr
}$$
The trick is to replace the Hadamard product by the normal matrix product with a diagonal matrix.